# Redirect to another page with request php

Tags: php, request

I have a php `a.php` where it accepts all the parameters posted to it by

```
$_REQUEST
```

I need to redirect the requests to b.php along with the $_REQUESTs received inside a.php.
How is this possible please help

Comment: Is `b.php` on the same site as `a.php`?

Comment: If you want to redirect requests with passing request data you have to use `cURL` or sockets

Comment: curl..How is it possible to pass all REQUEST by curl..Can u help?

Comment: why dont you use session.... like 
`$_SESSION['request'] = $_REQUEST;` and use `header()` to redirect to `b.php`...

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the data available to `b.php` then you could simply `include "b.php"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your a.php to redirect to b.php

```
$array=array($_REQUEST['name1'],$_REQUEST['name2']);//form your array
$array=json_encode($array); 

header('Location:b.php?q='.$array.'');
```

In b.php

```
$data=$_REQUEST['q'];
$data=json_decode($data);//you got array here and get the data from here
```

Use array with key values, it would be better

Comment: OP need to pass ALL request data

Comment: Yeah.I need to pass all REQUEST data

Comment: ALL request data means, can you form it as array?

Comment: You can form all data in a array and can send it as json data using json_encode($array). Is it possible to make array?

Comment: @SIBHIS Ya if I make it into and array,then how to redirect it?